# Expansion issue in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, verbatim

I would like to partially reproduce an example of the `tcolorbox` manual.
The end result (in section 24.1 page 461 of the current documentation) looks like
[image]
What I am interested in is to nest a `\DeclareTotalTCBox` with verbatim content inside of a `\tcbsidebyside`.

According to the documentation source code, this example is obtained with

```
\begin{dispExample*}{sbs,lefthand ratio=0.6}
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverb}{ v }{verbatim,
  colframe=red!75!black,colupper=blue}{#1}

\myverb{\textbf} is a \myverb{\LaTeX} command.
\end{dispExample*}
```

located in `doc\latex\tcolorbox\tcolorbox.doc.xparse.tex` (in the `tcolorbox` sources).

The `dispExample*` environment itself is defined in `tex\latex\tcolorbox\tcbdocumentation.code.tex` as

```
\def\enddispExample{%
  \endtcbwritetemp\endgroup%
  \begin{tcolorbox}%
  \tcb@doc@usetemplisting%
  \tcblower%
  \tcbusetemp%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newenvironment{dispExample*}[1]{%
  \tcb@layer@pushup\tcbset{docexample,#1}\begingroup\tcbwritetemp%
  }{\enddispExample}
```

which I can't make much sense of...

My current developments define an `\achtung` (hello to the german friends here) command based on a `\tcbsidebyside` and re-use the `\myverb` from the documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Affichage de boite pour mettre du contenu en évidence
\newcommand{\achtung}[1]{
    \tcbsidebyside[sidebyside adapt=left,colframe=orange,fonttitle=\bfseries,
        bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=orange!5!white,top=1mm,bottom=1mm]{%
        {}
    }{%
        #1
    }
}

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverb}{ v }{verbatim,colframe=red!75!black,colupper=blue}{#1}
    
\begin{document}
    \achtung{\lipsum[1] \myverb{blablabla}} % <--- remove the \myverb to make the example work.
\end{document}
```

The obvious reason for this to fail (that I can think of) is that the `\achtung` somehow swallows the argument of `\myverb` so some `\protect` or `\noexpand` may be of help.
Using the `\tcbsidebyside` directly does not seem to make much difference.

Comment: `\myverb` is declared to take a verbatim argument so, as usual with verbatim commands, it cannot appear in the argument to another command.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, I saw that... But as it is shown in examples, I figured it could be reproduced somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround with `verbatimbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum,verbatimbox}

% Affichage de boite pour mettre du contenu en évidence
\newcommand{\achtung}[1]{
    \tcbsidebyside[sidebyside adapt=left,colframe=orange,fonttitle=\bfseries,
        bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=orange!5!white,top=1mm,bottom=1mm]{%
        {}
    }{%
        #1
    }
}

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverb}{ v }{verbatim,colframe=red!75!black,colupper=blue}{#1}
    
\begin{document}
  \begin{myverbbox}{\bla}blablabla\end{myverbbox}
    \achtung{\lipsum[1] \bla} % <--- remove the \myverb to make the example work.
\end{document}
```

[image]